# Mail send form with attachment to stay on the same page

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I have a "Send mail" form in my webapp that allow users to send comments or suggestions about my app. At first I created a simple POST form that worked nicely, and after sending the mail reloaded the page with a "your mail was successfully sent" message.

The problem is when pressing back on the browser, it goes back to the same form page since it was added twice to the history stack.

So what I did was send the form post request via AJAX with jQuery and then just show the message when the response was ok. This is the code I am using:

```
$.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(),
    function (response) {
        var success = eval(response).success;
        if (success == '1')
            showSuccessDialog(successMessage);
        else
            showSuccessDialog(errorMessage);
    }, 'json')
    .fail(function (data) {
        showSuccessDialog(errorMessage);
    });
```

The problem is, I also have an "attachment" file input that works fine with the regular POST request, but does not get sent through my AJAX post request.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sending files over an XmlHttpRequest is supported only in newer browsers (read: IE10), so you may want to verify whether you're ready to do this.

If you are, have a look at the [FormData JavaScript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). It allows for sending files as well as your usual form data.

There are JS plugins that utilise this API, so you might want to look around and see if you can find something you can use. I'm currently putting one together, so you might want to have a look at the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/mingos/uupload/src/41ba11c0cd852aace3266fa265d8c220105040ac/src/uUpload/Uploader.js?at=dev) for reference.